# How to get predictions using cross-validation with catboost?

Tags: catboost

I'm looking at documentation
https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_cv
the function returns scores (metrics) and can return models (using return_models), but how to get predictions for pool (predictions for each fold must be made by model which didn't train of fold it evaluates on)?